# MySQL - Select rows with smallest id in their group

Tags: mysql

There was a programming mistake in my application that caused a table to triple its values.  Here's an example, showing which rows I need to keep and delete with comments.

```
'id'     'uuid'          'value'        'parent' 'idx'
-------------------------------------------------------
1,     uuid-1234,   ROW ONE VALUE HERE,   48,      2 /* Keep this */
78,    uuid-5678,   ROW ONE VALUE HERE,   48,      2 /* Delete this row */
79,    uuid-9999,   ROW ONE VALUE HERE,   48,      2 /* Delete this row */
```

I obviously need to fix the application problem that caused this, but in the mean time I want to delete the two or more rows with `id`s greater than the smallest `id`.  What SQL can I write to do this?  Right now, I'm just trying to `SELECT` these rows, and here is what I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
ORDER BY value;
```

This groups them together so I see the duplicated `value`s, but I'm at a loss as to how to SELECT the rows with `id`s greater than the smallest `id` of the group for each `value`.

Comment: i think you forgot `group by` in your query

Comment: You might look into an update statement using a correlated subquery.

Comment: `delete t1.* from my_table t1 join my_table t2 using(<group columns>) where t1.id > t2.id`. For